# jsp not passing UTF-8 data in proper format

Tags: java, jsp, utf-8, struts2, character-encoding

I want JSP pages to support UTF8 data I am able to localization with struts2 and jsp but when I take data from user on jsp in local language the information is not going in action in proper format it is passing some grabled data.
    Here is my jsp code :------

```xml
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/plain; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
      <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@page import="java.util.*"%>
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/plain; charset=UTF-8">
<title><s:text name="global.addnewcustomer"/></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:9090/AMCMSWeb/basic/validation/Login.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h2 align="center"><s:text name="global.fillinfo"/></h2>
    <s:form action="addcustomeraction" method="post" acceptcharset="UTF-8">

<table align="center" border="1" bgcolor="pink" bordercolor="gray">
<tr>
    <td><s:text name="global.custName"/></td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td><s:textfield name="custName" size="15"></s:textfield></td>
    <td><s:text name="global.custMidleName"/></td><td>:</td><td><s:textfield name="custMidleName" size="15"></s:textfield></td>
    <td><s:text name="global.custLastName"/></td><td>:</td><td><s:textfield name="custLastName" size="15"></s:textfield></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><s:text name="global.mobileNo"/></td><td>:</td><td><s:textfield name="mobileNo" size="15"></s:textfield></td>
    <td><s:text name="global.phoneNo"/></td><td>:</td><td><s:textfield name="phoneNo" size="15"></s:textfield></td>
    <td><s:text name="global.toDate"/>&nbsp;<s:label>(mmm/dd/yyyy)</s:label></td><td>:</td><td><s:textfield name="toDate" size="15" readonly="true">
                <s:param name="value">
                        <s:date name="new java.util.Date()" format="MM/dd/yyyy"/>
                </s:param>
    </s:textfield></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><s:text name="global.atPost"/></td><td>:</td><td><s:textarea name="atPost" cols="15" rows="3"></s:textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><s:text name="global.taluka"/></td><td>:</td><td><s:select list="#{'Miraj':'Miraj','Haveli':'Haveli'}" name="taluka" headerKey="-1" headerValue="Select Taluka" ></s:select></td>
    <td><s:text name="global.district"/></td><td>:</td><td><s:select list="#{'Sangli':'Sangli','Pune':'Pune'}" name="district" headerKey="-1" headerValue="Select District"></s:select></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><s:text name="global.state"/></td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td><s:select list="#{'Maharashtra':'Maharashtra','Karnataka':'Karnataka'}" name="state" headerKey="-1" headerValue="Select State" onchange="list_districts()"></s:select></td>
    <td><s:text name="global.country"/></td><td>:</td><td><s:select  list="#{'India':'India'}" name="country" headerKey="-1" headerValue="Select Country" ></s:select></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><s:text name="global.pinCode"/></td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td><s:textfield name="pinCode"  type="" size="15"></s:textfield></td>
</tr>
</table>

<table align="center" >
     <tr>
        <td><s:submit name="s" key="global.proceed"/></td>  
        <td><input type="button" name="cancel" value="  X  "></td>
     </tr>
</table>
    </s:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which application server are you using?

Answer (score 1):

The character encoding specified in the page (or in the web.xml) is applied to the following phases of an HTTP communication:

1. Preparing / sending the Request from the Client to the Server
2. <s>Receiving / reading the Request in the Server</s>
3. Preparing / sending the Response from the Server to the Client
4. Receiving / reading the Response in the Client

The **Application Server** is the only responsible for the phase 2.

You need to look for your specific application server settings, to alter the default character encoding (that could easily be `ISO-8859-1`), and alter it to work in `UTF-8`.

For example, in Tomcat you would need to edit the `conf/server.xml` file, by adding the `URIEncoding="UTF-8"` parameter to the `<Connector>`, for example from

```
<Connector port="8090" />
```

to

```
<Connector port="8090" URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>
```

[In the Apache Wiki there is a nice list of things to check](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding) to make sure all your components are running in UTF-8:

> **What can you recommend to just make everything work? (How to use UTF-8
>   everywhere).**
>
> Using UTF-8 as your character encoding for everything is a safe bet.
>   This should work for pretty much every situation.
>
> In order to completely switch to using UTF-8, you need to make the
>   following changes:
>
> 1. Set URIEncoding="UTF-8" on your  in server.xml. References: [HTTP
>      Connector](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html),
>      [AJP
>      Connector](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/ajp.html).
> 2. Use a [character encoding filter](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding#Q3) with
>      the default encoding set to UTF-8
> 3. Change all your JSPs to include charset name in their contentType.    For example, use `<%@page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>`
>      for the usual JSP pages and `<jsp:directive.page
>      contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />` for the pages in XML syntax
>      (aka JSP Documents).
> 4. Change all your servlets to set the content type for responses and to include charset name in the content type to be UTF-8.    Use
>      `response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8")` or
>      `response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8")`.
> 5. Change any content-generation libraries you use (Velocity, Freemarker, etc.) to use UTF-8 and to specify UTF-8 in the content
>      type of the responses that they generate.
> 6. Disable any valves or filters that may read request parameters before your character encoding filter or jsp page has a chance to set
>      the encoding to UTF-8. For more information see
>      http://www.mail-archive.com/users@tomcat.apache.org/msg21117.html.