# Problems with accented characters in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, encoding, struts2

I am trying to collect accented characters [áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ] on a form but are not correctly sent to action:

JSP:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
[. . .]
<s:form action="resultRot" method="post" theme="simple">
<s:textfield name="param" theme="simple" size="20" maxlength="20" style="text-transform: uppercase; text-align:center"/>
<s:submit name="submit" key="ejercicios.roturaPalabras.corregir" align="center"/>
```

When I pick the parameter param in the action class, it does not contain the correct values.
I use Eclipse and I checked out the project encoding is ISO-8859-1

I´ve tried with UTF-8 encoding too (in my jsp):

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

I´ve tried with URLDecoder/Encoder too:

```
String prueba = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(solucionIntroducida, "ISO-8859-1");
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ISO-8859-1 doesn't contain those characters in the charset.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best practice is to use `UTF-8` everywhere.

[Here you can find how to do it by altering the application server's connectors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17409254/1654265), while for the other parts you can simply specify it in each `JSP` (like you are doing), or specify it once in `web.xml`:

```
<jsp-config>
    <jsp-property-group>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
        <page-encoding>UTF-8</page-encoding>
    </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>
```

To debug (and print) a `Request` in **Eclipse**, you need to ensure that you are using `UTF-8` as *text file encoding*.

Go to <kbd>Preferences</kbd> -> <kbd>General</kbd> -> <kbd>Workspace</kbd> -> <kbd>Text file encoding</kbd> , and set `Other: UTF-8`

In the code, be sure to always specify the character encoding when converting String to Byte[] or viceversa:

```
String str = new String(myByteArray,"UTF-8");
```

and

```
byte[] ba = myString.toByteArray("UTF-8");
```

This are the steps needed in order to preserve the correct characters everywhere.

Comment: Thanks, your solution worked for parameters with accents.
Now, the problem happens when I use a properties file, the file must be with ISO-8859-1 encoding instead of UTF8 to display text correctly.
This is not a big problem.
The main problem is reading words with accents from a text file and display them in a jsp, it displays the correct characters with ISO-8859-1 but no with UTF8.

Comment: I use FileInputStream for reading files line by line:

     FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(nameFile);
     
     DataInputStream entry = new DataInputStream(fstream);
     
     BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(entry));
     
     String strLine;
     
     while ((strLine = buffer.readLine()) != null)   {
     
          result.add(strLine);
          
     }

Comment: It works! Using the method with the encoding ISO-8859-1 (with UTF8 it doesn´t work)
     `File fileDir = new File(nombreFichero);
 BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fileDir), "ISO-8859-1"));
 String strLine;
 while ((strLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
  resultado.add(strLine);
 }
 in.close();`
Thanks!