# Java UTF-8 encoding not working HttpURLConnection

Tags: java

I tried to do post call and to pass input with this value - "ä€愛لآहที่"
I got error message

```
{"error":{"code":"","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":{"type":"ODataInputError","message":"Bad Input: Invalid JSON format"}}}}
```

This is my code

```
    conn.setRequestMethod(ConnectionMethod.POST.toString());
    conn.setRequestProperty(CONTENT_LENGTH, Integer.toString(content.getBytes().length));
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8"); 
    conn.setUseCaches(false);
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
    wr.writeBytes(content);
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();
    InputStream resultContentIS;
    String resultContent;
    try {
        resultContentIS = conn.getInputStream();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(resultContentIS));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }
```

it falied on conn.getInputStream();

The value of content is

```
{ "input" : "ä€愛لآहที่" }
```

It is working where the input is String or integer

When I added the statement

```
   conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8");
```

I got different message

```
 {"error":{"code":"","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":{"type":"Error","message":"Internal server error"}}}}
```

Comment: it depends on how you read the input stream. Please provide a few more lines of code so we can help.

Comment: it failed on conn.getInputStream()

Comment: From where `content` comes from ? Is it hard-coded ? Do you have UTF-8 charset set on your IDE ?

Comment: the content get from the user, I am using eclipse kepler

Comment: Read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17649413/1654265) and [this other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17409254/1654265) too.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Please try this code below:

```
DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(wr, "UTF-8"));
writer.write(content);
writer.close();
wr.close();
```

You should use JSONObject to pass params

The input, please try

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(resultContentIS, "UTF-8"));
```

If the out put is: ???????, so do not worry because your output console do not support UTF-8

Comment: It worked but I got as result more chars this is the output ¤â¬æÙØ¢à¤¹à¸à¸µà¹

Comment: did you try with org.json.JSONObject? and then `code`writer.write(json.toString());

Comment: You use JSONObject to set the key and value for your contain like this `code` JSONObject content = new JSONObject(); content.put("input", "ä€愛لآहที่");

Comment: I used it but now the problem the when I do reader.readLine() I got more charterers then the input

Comment: please try again: `code` BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(resultContentIS, "UTF-8"));

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37246/discussion-between-user1365697-and-ha-nguyen)

Comment: could you inserted to the chat ?

Comment: Worked perfectly for my android app.
Thanks a ton.

Comment: The `DataOutputStream` is not necessary.

Comment: thanks , it worked for me

Answer (score 3):

It seems that your variable *content* does already have the wrong data because you may have converted a String without any attention to the required encoding.

Setting the correct enconding on the writer and use `write()` instead of `writeBytes()` should be worth a try.

Comment: I changed it to wr.write(content.getBytes()); and not it worked but Now the output is ????????

Comment: Is `content` a string? When you do `content.getBytes();` it uses the default character encoding of your system, which may or may not be UTF-8. If it must be UTF-8, do `content.getBytes("UTF-8");`.

Comment: the content is a string,It worked but it added more ouput. the new output is Ã¤â¬æÙØ¢à¤¹à¸à¸µà¹ and the input was ä€愛لآहที่. I just return the inout that I got

Comment: now the problem the when I do reader.readLine() I got more charterers then the input

Answer (score 1):

You have to send content via byte array

```
 DataOutputStream outputStream= new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
 outputStream.write(content.toString().getBytes());
```

This is completely solution for your file name character problems. The imported point is string sending via byte array. Every character changing via byte character. This is prevent your character encoding problems.