# How to use accent mark in data base from my app?

Tags: java, android, diacritics

I have a data base and it works but i can't use accent mark, it doesn't detect nothing.

My code:

`public class Admin extends AppCompatActivity {`

```
EditText titulo_in;
EditText descripcion_in;
Button btnActualizarA;


String recuperado="";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.admin);

    titulo_in = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.titulo_in);
    descripcion_in = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.descripcion_in);

   // titu = titulo_in.getText().toString();
    //desc = descripcion_in.getText().toString();



    final Bundle recupera=getIntent().getExtras();
    if(recupera!=null){
        recuperado=recupera.getString("cod");
    }

    btnActualizarA=(Button)findViewById(R.id.publicar);
    btnActualizarA.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Thread tr2=new Thread(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    ActualizarPost(recuperado, titulo_in.getText().toString(), descripcion_in.getText().toString());

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Se ha completado la publicación", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                }
            };
            tr2.start();
        }
    });


}

public void ActualizarPost(String c, String tit, String des){
    String urlParameters="cod="+c+"&tit="+tit+"&des="+des;
   // HttpURLConnection conection=null;
    try{
        URL url=new URL("http://rudeboys.esy.es/ramiroconnect/publicar.php");
        HttpURLConnection conection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
       // conection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","UTF-8");

        //estableciendo el metodo
        conection.setRequestMethod("POST");

        //longitud de datos que se envian
        conection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + Integer.toString(urlParameters.getBytes().length));
       // conection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");


        //comando para la salida de datos
        conection.setDoOutput(true);

        DataOutputStream wr=new DataOutputStream(conection.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
        wr.close();
        InputStream is =conection.getInputStream();

    }catch (Exception ex){}
}
```

}

**My problem is where should I put "UTF-8" and how?** I am sure that this is my problem, but when I use "UTF-8" neither works. How I put it?

(My data base works without accent marks)

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/18760096/1722236

Comment: I need more help because my doubt is different, my conection works! only I need use accent marks T.T

Comment: and your link have a lot of incomplete, answers , but thanks. if somebody  can help.

Comment: i am trying use your answer with utf-8 but nothing.... some idea?

Comment: Not sure if you got my point. Could you try to wrap your DataOutputStream into an OutpustreamWriter and a Buffered writer ? 
DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(wr, "UTF-8")); Also which encoding does your DB supports ? Are accents removed or accented letters replaced by "symbols" ?

Comment: Yes I have ``DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(conection.getOutputStream());`` and ``BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(wr, "UTF-8"));`` with ``writer.write(urlParameters);`` and `` writer.close();`` I tried `` String titleUtf8 = URLEncoder.encode(tit, "utf-8").replaceAll("\\+", "%20");`` and  ``String descriptionUtf8 = URLEncoder.encode(des, "utf-8").replaceAll("\\+", "%20");`` and ``String urlParameters="cod="+c+"&tit="+titleUtf8+"&des="+descriptionUtf8;`` **but not works with accent marks**. letters with accents are removed, and also the word.

Comment: Example: camión casá --> becomes --> cami  ( the word _casá_  disappears and the word _camión_ only appear "cami" .